# dynamically added item does not trigger materilizedcss modal using jquery in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

This is a to do list project where clicking on each item triggers a modal div where the item can be edited or deleted. everything works fine, however, When I add a new item and click on it the modal div does not open.
here is the project on codepen:

https://codepen.io/abdolsa/pen/MpKYOp?editors=0010

I suspect the problem is coming from these lines.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

I also used the following method with no success ...

```
$(document).on('click', function()
{
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
});
```

Thank you for reading. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What does your console say? Are there any errors?

Comment: No errors in the console. I assume that the jquery snippet does not attach events to  dynamically created elements only to the elements that are loaded at start. however, not sue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code inside the handleSave() function.

```
$('.modal-new').leanModal();
```

In line 94 add a new class to the div, "modal-new"

```
<a className="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red modal-trigger scale-out modal-new" href="#modal1" onClick={this.handleAdd}>
```

Try whether this is working

Comment: The popup for the new item is not working because the new item is a generated element and for which the leanModal is not registered :) We have to register this for a newly generated div :) Also there are different ways to do this. This is a simple method :)

Comment: it works two times but then the modal does not go away. :(  is there any other way you suggest trying?

Comment: Can you check the console? Whether it is showing any error?

Comment: so that not only does not trigger modal on new items but after adding the second item the div with "lead-overlay" class does not close :(